# Linked list compiler error

Tags: c, compiler-errors, linked-list

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct{
    int data;
    struct Node* next;
}Node;

Node* head;

void AddEntry(){
    int x;
    Node* temp;
    temp = head;
    while(temp != NULL){
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    Node* temp1 = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    temp->next = temp1;
    printf("What is the value for this entry?\n");
    scanf("%d",&x);
    temp1->data = x;
    temp1->next = NULL;
}
void PrintList(){
    Node* temp;
}



int main(void){

}
```

When I compile this code I get the compiler error:

```
pointertest.c: In function ‘AddEntry’:

pointertest.c:16:8: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
   temp = temp->next;
        ^
pointertest.c:19:13: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
  temp->next = temp1;
```

I am not understanding why that is. I’ve seen this done in my textbook and elsewhere. I thought it was assigning the pointer temp to address saved in temp next.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your structure definition is bogus.  Try this instead:

```
typedef struct tagNode {
  int data;
  struct tagNode *next;
} Node;
```

In your code, there is no such thing as a `struct Node`, there is just an unnamed structure with an "alias" (`typedef`) called `Node`.

By defining it this way, you can declare of variable of this type by doing either:

```
struct tagNode foo;
```

Or:

```
Node foo;
```

But when I `typedef` a `struct` like this, I avoid using the tag to avoid confusion.

It has been brought up in comments that it might be confusing why I chose to use `struct tagNode` instead of `struct Node`.  Both work equally well, but my personal preference is to use different names to avoid confusion later on. I find it easier to visually disambiguate `struct tagNode *foo` from `Node *foo` then if I had just used `struct Node`.

Comment: So that extra term tagNode is used when you need to reference the struct inside the declaration?

Comment: Yes.  There are other ways to do the same thing, but that is one way of doing it.

Comment: I was always wondering why that was only sometimes included. Makes perfect sense, thanks so much!

Comment: Why change from `struct Node` (which is already in use in his code) to `struct tagNode`? I've never had a problem with the struct name overlapping with a typedef... is there some issue?

Comment: There's no compelling reason to use a different name for the typedef. This answer is potentially misleading as it implies a different name is needed for the incomplete type reference inside the struct definition.

Comment: @mah - There is no problem, but I believe it helps to avoid confusion.  It's fine either way.

Comment: I don't think that can cause confusion, what does cause confusion is `typedef`ing `struct Node *`.

Answer (score 3):

There is no `struct Node` in your code.

This is a `typedef` for an anonymous structure

```
typedef struct {
    int data;
    struct Node* next;
} Node;
```

which is valid in c, but up to here there is no `struct Node` declared at all, you need

```
typedef struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node* next;
} Node;
```

If you are going to `typedef` it anyway, you can do it like this too

```
typedef struct Node Node;
struct Node
 {
    int   data;
    Node *next;
 };
```